# Stop ng-class from appearing until resolved

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using `ng-class` with the ternary operator to dynamically set a glyphicon. My problem is that whatever glyphicon is set in the `else` block appears for a second before the expression is resolved. Below is my HTML. `header` is simply the scope from my controller, and `header.status` is set in my controller after data is fetched from my API.

```
<i ng-class="header.status === 'single' ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-user pull-left' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-parents pull-left'"></i>
```

Note: I tried adding `ng-cloak`, but it made no difference.

Comment: It appears because if `header.status` is single or not there is a glyphicon set. Or I didn't understand. EDIT: Probably with an `ng-show="header.status"` you solve your problem?

Comment: Do you want to hide the `<i>` entirely? Or just not add any class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to hide the `<i>`, you could use ng-show:

```
<i ng-show="header.status" ng-class="header.status === 'single' ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-user pull-left' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-parents pull-left'"></i>
```

If you want to hide all classes until `header.status` is set, you could add another ternary:

```
<i ng-class="header.status ? (header.status === 'single' ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-user pull-left' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-parents pull-left') : ''"></i>
```

Or better yet, add a neat array to your controller:

```
$scope.statusArray = [];
dataService.getData().then(function() {
    $scope.statusArray.push("glyphicon", "pull-left");
    if(header.status === 'single') {
        $scope.statusArray.push("glyphicon-user");
    }
    else {
        $scope.statusArray.push("glyphicon-parents");
    }
});
```

And use that as your ng-class:

```
<i ng-class="statusArray"></i>
```

[Sort of non-representative Fiddle :)](http://jsfiddle.net/z67g8d2L/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ng-cloak to the `<i>` and then add the css below to the style sheet of your page

```
[ng:cloak], 
[ng-cloak], 
[data-ng-cloak], 
[x-ng-cloak], 
.ng-cloak, 
.x-ng-cloak {
   display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

```
<i ng-class="{'glyphicon':true, 'pull-left': true, 'glyphicon-user': header.status === 'single', 'glyphicon-parents': header.status && header.status !== 'single'}"></i>
```